# How can I use XElement to retrieve the Sum of an Attribute?

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I've been using XElement to store information about files, and I would like to be able to sum all of the file lengths to get a total size of the files.

I keep wanting the answer to be something like this...

```
xmlDir.Elements("File").Attributes("Length").Sum();
```

I think the answer probably uses a lambda expression, but I don't know how to frame it.

I've found answers that tell me how to sum elements in XElement, but none showing how to sum values of an attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DirectoryDetails Path="F:\IndianSprings\Condensates" SerialNumber="10092693">
  <File Name="Start Menu\Programs\Games\Minesweeper.lnk" Length="1515" DateLastModified="2010-03-15T18:09:25.2325712-04:00" DateCreated="2010-08-16T05:11:39.171875-04:00" />
  <File Name="Start Menu\Programs\Games\Pinball.lnk" Length="885" DateLastModified="2010-03-15T18:09:25.2225568-04:00" DateCreated="2010-08-16T05:11:39.1875-04:00" />
  <File Name="Start Menu\Programs\Games\Solitaire.lnk" Length="1491" DateLastModified="2010-03-15T18:09:25.2325712-04:00" DateCreated="2010-08-16T05:11:39.21875-04:00" />
  <File Name="Start Menu\Programs\Games\Spider Solitaire.lnk" Length="1502" DateLastModified="2010-03-15T18:09:25.2425856-04:00" DateCreated="2010-08-16T05:11:39.515625-04:00" />
</DirectoryDetails>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you almost got it

```
var result = xmlDir.Elements("File").Attributes("Length").Sum(a=>(int)a);
```

`a` is XAttribute and XAttribute supports explicit cast to `int` (`(int)a`)

Comment: Excellent!  Now if I can just figure out why it came out one byte off...  LOL

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this 
var v=   xmlDir.Elements("File").Attributes("Length").Sum( x => (int)x);